# Highstock: setting the navigator's xAxis min and max

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock charts, and there is a requirement to show line graphs with a fixed x-axis range, irrespective of the data. Setting the xAxis min and max properties accomplishes that for me.

The trouble comes when I try to use the navigator. The API documentation says that the you can include an xAxis object in the navigator options which can contain all of the same properties, but here, setting the min and max properties doesn't seem to do anything: the xAxis on the navigator still begins and ends at the data min and data max. Instead, I'm trying to get it to use the same xAxis settings as the main chart.

I've thought about inserting fake data points into the series at the desired min and max (with a value of null), but was hoping there was a better way to accomplish this.

A simple example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/j6GFq/2

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: {},

    navigator: {
        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            ordinal: false
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        ordinal: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [10, 20],
            [20, 40],
            [50, 10]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Adding null points is fine solution - navigator sets extremes according to data from first series.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go with that approach then. I must say though, it does seem weird that the navigator's xAxis shouldn't just accept the same min and max settings.

Comment: One final note: I did try one variation, which was to have a separate data series for the navigator which contained the original data plus the extra null points. This set the xAxis on the navigator as I expected, but as you mention, the handlebars for the extremes were still set according to the data from the first series. As a result the time range indicated on the navigator was incorrect, which seems like a bug: http://jsfiddle.net/j6GFq/3/

Comment: You have also option to add another series only with these two null points instead, see: http://jsfiddle.net/j6GFq/4/ Regarding your example - I will report that, thanks!

Comment: @PawełFus, I've also experienced this problem, and tried your jsfiddle, but noted that it fails when you slide the right-hand slider of the navigator.  If you return the slider to it's furthest position, the main chart jumps so the last data point is on the right-hand side of the graph.  The left-hand slider works as expected.  Windows Firefox, Highstock 1.3.7.